# slideToggle: Hiding a parent by clicking a child link

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I've got a `<nav>` that I want to reveal by clicking a handle link to open and close. I'd also like to close the `<nav>` when I click one of the child links. Using `slideToggle` on both the handle link and children isn't working. The handle link works just fine, but the `<nav>` collapses and opens back up when you click on a child link.

jsFiddle of what's going on:
http://jsfiddle.net/qHZe8/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two elements with class `pull`.

One possible solution is to use different selector:

```
jQuery("a.pull").click(function() {
    $("nav.mobile-navigation").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qHZe8/1/

Answer (score 3):

Your `<ul>` element also has the class `pull`, so clicking on one of the links inside it is also firing off a `click` event handler to toggle the element again.

You'll need to stop the event propagating from the links inside the `<ul>` so that this doesn't happen.

```
jQuery("ul.pull li a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("nav.mobile-navigation").slideUp("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the same class in the ul and in the link to open it, so whenever you click in the child links it executes both actions.

If you remove the class from the ul tag it should work

http://jsfiddle.net/slfede/qHZe8/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have given the same CSS class (`.pull`) to both the `<ul>` and the handle. Hence a click on the items registers as a click for the `.pull` handler too. The correct one: http://jsfiddle.net/X2A3C/